# How to match exact word with regex

Tags: ruby

This is my code -

```
text = '-ice'
text.sub!(/[ice]{3}/i, 'NONE')
puts text
```

The output is "-NONE". But, I want the output to be "-ice". How do I do it ?

Comment: It's not clear what you exactly want to match.

Comment: @YuHao - I want the text to be replaced only if it is EXACTLY ice using the above code. coolice, ice-t, soft-ice etc should not be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want exact matches, regexes are overkill. Just do a string equality test.

```
text = "NONE" if text.downcase == "ice"
```

But if you are insistent on using regexes, just anchor the regexp:

```
text.sub! /\Aice\z/i, "NONE"
```

Comment: Thanks! What does the \A and \z do ?

Comment: They anchor to the start and end of the string. They're like ^ and $, except ^ and $ match the beginning and end of a line, rather than the beginning and end of the input. If you had the string `soft\nice` then `^ice$` would match, while `\Aice\z` will not.